# Swift: UITextView unselectable inside UIStackView

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I know that this question exists a few times, however, none of the answers have helped me fix this issue.

I have a scrollview that has a few textfields inside of it. It all works fine, except for the textfield. Those are not selectable, no matter what I do. I have many views with TextFields which I have implemented in the same manner, and those work. I am out of ideas.

My ScrollView

```
let scrollView = UIScrollView()
scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
```

Inside the Scrollview is first a ContentView, which might be useless but thats how I have always done it. This just spreads out to the ScrollView.
Inside the ContentView is a StackView (vertical), which keeps all of the Content inside it.
Inside the StackView is, for example, the following Text Field Stack (A Title, a TextField and an Error Label

My TextField Stack

```
//First Name Field
let firstNameStack = UIStackView()
firstNameStack.axis = .vertical
firstNameStack.spacing = 5
firstNameStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
firstNameTextFieldTitle.text = "firstName"
firstNameTextFieldTitle.textColor = colors.justWhite
firstNameTextFieldTitle.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-SemiBold", size: 14)
firstNameTextFieldTitle.textAlignment = .left
firstNameTextFieldTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
firstNameTextField.textColor = colors.justWhite
firstNameTextField.backgroundColor = colors.lightyLightGray
firstNameTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "first name".localized, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]) //ID12
firstNameTextField.font =  UIFont.init(name: "montserrat", size: 18)
firstNameTextField.autocorrectionType = .no
firstNameTextField.textAlignment = .left
firstNameTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 5
firstNameTextField.clipsToBounds = true
firstNameTextField.setLeftPaddingPoints(10)
firstNameTextField.setRightPaddingPoints(10)
firstNameTextField.keyboardType = .default
firstNameTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
firstNameTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
firstNameTextField.delegate = self
    
firstNameTextFieldError.textColor = colors.errorRed
firstNameTextFieldError.textAlignment = .left
firstNameTextFieldError.font =  UIFont(name: "Montserrat-SemiBold", size: 14)
firstNameTextFieldError.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

firstNameStack.addArrangedSubview(firstNameTextFieldTitle)
firstNameStack.addArrangedSubview(firstNameTextField)
firstNameStack.addArrangedSubview(firstNameTextFieldError)
```

The View lays out perfectly. No issue there. I can open the Keyboard using becomeFirstResponder(), but tapping on them does nothing. I feel stupid for overseeing something very simple, for sure.

I have added the delegate to close the keyboard when dismissing and just to be sure, I added

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
    return true
}
```

What's the issue here? Looking forward to any tips.

Comment: try remove all of your ``translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints``

Comment: @bewithyou since I didn't set any frames, doing this just removes everything from the screen. Do constraints break the Touches?

Comment: Keep ``translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`` of your stack view and try remove from your text field and test again. Yes in some cases when I deal with this it breaks touches because you setting wrong.

Comment: @bewithyou I tried removing it from as much as possible without breaking the ui. This did not help though. How could I be setting it wrong? I set it to false and then add NSLayoutConstraints to that element. It worked well so far

Comment: Yes, can you give me full github of how you implement above? It not full of all your constraints and how you implement it in your viewcontroller

Comment: @bewithyou thanks for your quick help. I have solved the issue as stated in my answer! The issue could not be seen in this code indeed. Didn't expect that line to be the issue...

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue, it was indeed my own stupidity. For anyone as blind as myself:

Be careful when adding Views to a StackView. I used StackView.addSubview(View) instead of StackView.add**Arranged**Subview(View), because I was doing it quickly using auto-complete. This seems to have broken the StackView and thus the touch recognizers.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to share the solution to your problem. (Voted.) Once SO allows it, you should accept your self-answer so other people can tell that the question has been answered.